# Disabling tabs generated by Angular Strap (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm creating some tabs in my HTML page for which Im using `AngularStrap` library. I want to disable one of the tab in it.

My code :

```
<div bs-tabs>
<div data-title="General">     <!-- the tab which needs to be disabled -->
</div>
</div>
```

I tried using `ng-show`, `ng-disabled` and `ng-if` -- But it doesn't get disabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you really tried ng-if? It wouldn't even add the tab to DOM if the ng-if expression was false

Comment: Yes, I tried adding ng-if and as you told, it does not add tab in DOM, but requirement is that tab should be present but disabled.

Comment: its been a long time since you asked this question. Could you resolve it?

Comment: I tried hiding tab using ng-if condition,because disable tab did not work for me

Comment: ng-if adds an extra double tab for me...

Answer (score 3):

This is something that has been [fixed in 2.1.3](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/commit/c5bc2ac3c214ddecf2b2372021d1dd57ebea8b95).

After upgrading, 'ng-if' should be enough:

```
                    <div ng-model="tabs.activeTab" bs-tabs="">
                    <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" title="{{ tab.title }}" bs-pane="" ng-if="tab.show">
                        <div ng-include="tab.page"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a [disabled option for bs-pane](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/releases/tag/v2.2.0) (version 2.2.0 onwards)